# Vega lite heatmap incorrect with multi line calculated field

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have plotted a simple heatmap (minimal example [Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoCOswMD6AHJ9MNUopX6oAJxo47ctCACiADyQEHEE4AAIAJkcAMzYXBG8ACR8ATQB9AFkASRAAXwUTMwtvGwo7ByVlZzcPdnl0f0DgsMilGLjvADUAeQ6M7LyCtSLrW3s4R0roas86kC7ZcdbY+PQALQBBZMyrVIAVH1z8kFMhyxAStTGJqvcZ7wagkIjo5cSUvsPB8zOLssWnKa3Wreeb-NorEBJNK7LqfY6FH6jcoA1xArzoUEvdprTbbPawnIAXTyIEwLiQsgg4KMoCgOigDEEanG6AgwToAApVOYEJRJqianIFKEAOSigCUjiQZ3501qkSJSmQLgA1mhQJgAJ44FkgFxwKCYRyYNhsQR2HBoMl6ElwWRQNjKGiyMjqkB+N1RGhwQTKbyytGyFogJB+GiWUBMpg+9YukJofgAFjEORJms93t93mpSjsmHj6AAYq8SQ7BLE3UgyGR9aVdQ6GLIjbm6AXzmxKKE2FFQs6oDRKk2DKmckA) ) which initially appeared correct.

Many labels were very long so I added the transform `{"calculate": "split(datum.description, ' ')", "as": "description2"}` to split labels into new lines on the space character (`description` being the field mapped to the `x` axis).

However the plot is now incorrect. In the linked spec, if you change the encoding of `x` from `"field": "description2"` to `"field": "description"` the entire plot changes. Many items with description of `One` do not plot correctly when using field `description2` (the calculated field) but do when using field `description`.

Why does the calculated field break the plot, and is there an alternative way to deal with long labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a labelExpr. The calculated field is breaking the plot because you're passing an array as a field value.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"status": "Negative", "description": "Example 2", "form": "HEY_MI"},
      {"status": "Negative", "description": "Example 2", "form": "VOV_MI"},
      {"status": "Negative", "description": "One", "form": "ZAYIN_TE"},
      {"status": "Negative", "description": "Example 2", "form": "HEY_MI"},
      {"status": "Negative", "description": "One", "form": "HEY_TO"},
      {"status": "Negative", "description": "One", "form": "ZAYIN_TO"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "rect", "tooltip": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "description",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": -90, "labelExpr": "split(datum.label, ' ')"}
    },
    "y": {"field": "form", "title": "Form"},
    "color": {"aggregate": "count", "title": "No. of incidents"}
  }
}
```